# spark parquet table data hdfs folder permssion issue

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, parquet

I am facing issue with the hdfs folders created as part of the spark job. Before the folders were getting created with 774 . But  recently its getting created with 700 . We havent changed any code so wondering in the spark Infra upgrade would have caused it . Where can i check this ?

SPARK VERSION  2.3.0.cloudera3
HIVE  VERSION 1.1.0-cdh5.16.1

Comment: Have you checked `fs.permissions.umask-mode` in hdfs-site.xml?

Comment: @mazaneicha .thanks for reply chked the same its 027 so this means no role for others rit. Since this is cluster level setup and is used by multiple teams not sure if i can get it changed t the cluster level. is there a way to override this behaviour to alow read for others at the application level?

Comment: I got from another thread that i can specify --conf spark.hadoop.fs.permissions.umask-mode at startup